# Order for search with soundcloud api

Tags: java, api, soundcloud

How can i get the sort order of my search results to be just like the one at soundcloud.com? When i search at soundcloud.com; it doesn't look it's sorted for hotness or created_at.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the network traffic, you will find the following API call:

https://api.soundcloud.com/e1/me/stream?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=xxx

Comment: To elaborate (and integrate what @IceFog said into a comment), "sniffing" is done by applications such as Fiddler and Wireshark.